# Navaid information on SID

Tags: instrument-flight-rules, navaids

I noticed this information under the navaid boxes on the Logan Four departure from KBOS. What do they mean? Additionally could you point me to what publication they would be explained in?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Those are the low- and high-altitude enroute charts where you find Boston VOR.

There is a PDF document called Legends & General Information that is found on the bottom of the terminal procedures website from the FAA.

https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/flight_info/aeronav/digital_products/dtpp/search/

[image]

---

**L-34 Chart**

https://skyvector.com/?ll=42.34991942247282,-70.99089362657521&chart=434&zoom=3

[image]

**L33 Chart**

https://skyvector.com/?ll=42.349950457479316,-70.99094187247229&chart=433&zoom=3

[image]

Comment: And just for SA, those enroute chart references and the lat/long coordinates are going away.

Comment: https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/flight_info/aeronav/acf/media/RDs/22-01-371_Enroute_Refs_Coordinates_on_DPs_STARs.pdf